# How to compare string data with real date

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

Need some help. Try compare string time with realt time.

```
<div ng-if="{{currentTime | date:'H:M'}} > {{stingtime}}">Hide</div>
```

Where currentTime is:

```
$scope.currentTime = new Date();
```

And {{stingtime}} is parsed from JSON time looks like 18:35

Finnaly I try compare time ex: 13:45 with string 18:45

Comment: Is `stingtime` a date object?

Comment: No is simple text object